# Stacked Bar Chart With No Fill?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, geom-bar, geom-col

I have a dataset all set up and am just trying to get a stacked bar chart to show.

My X-Axis will show three bars: "left", "middle", and "right"

My Y-Axis will be the "total_completed_epa" associated with each of the bars.

The only problem is that "total_completed_epa" is a mutated variable created by the sum of two other columns in my data-set. I just want to show the proportion that each of the columns had on the "total_completed_epa" with a stacked bar chart.

The data is:

```
    
pass_location Air_Epa_Play YAC_EPA_Play Total_Completed_EPA
middle         0.263         0.434           0.697
left           0.086         0.439           0.525
right          0.082         0.442           0.524
```

Scraping The Data:

```
pass_epa <- pbp_2018 %>%
  filter(play_type %in% c("pass", "no_play", "qb_spike"),
         epa != is.na(epa)) %>%
  group_by (pass_location) %>%
  summarize(pass_epa = sum(epa),
            air_epa = sum(comp_air_epa),
            yac_epa = sum(comp_yac_epa),
            pass_plays = n ()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(EPA_Play = round(pass_epa / pass_plays, 3),
         Air_Epa_Play = round(air_epa / pass_plays, 3), 
         YAC_EPA_Play = round(yac_epa / pass_plays, 3),
         Total_Completed_EPA = Air_Epa_Play + YAC_EPA_Play) %>%
  slice(-1) %>% 
  arrange(-EPA_Play) %>% 
  filter(pass_plays >= 80) %>%
  select(pass_location, Air_Epa_Play, YAC_EPA_Play, Total_Completed_EPA)
```

So I have just the 4 columns in my data set. The Air_Epa_Play and YAC_EPA_Play is summed into a "Total_Completed_EPA".

Visualizing It:

```
ggplot(pass_epa, aes(x = pass_location, y = Total_Completed_EPA, fill = ?)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

I just cannot get the Air_EPA_Play and YAC_EPA_Play to stack in the barchart for Total_Completed_EPA

[image]

Comment: Why don't you copy/paste the data, instead of showing us a picture of it? Would be much more useful.

Comment: sorry just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data

```
test <- data.frame(pass_location=c('middle','left','right'), Air_Epa_Play=c(0.263,0.086,0.082), YAC_Epa_Play=c(0.434,0.439,0.442), Total_Completed=c(0.697,0.525,0.524))

  pass_location Air_Epa_Play YAC_Epa_Play Total_Completed
1        middle        0.263        0.434           0.697
2          left        0.086        0.439           0.525
3         right        0.082        0.442           0.524
```

You can ignore the `Total_Completed` column - `select(-Total_Completed)`. `ggplot` does the stacking/summation for you so you don't have to calculate the total yourself. However, `ggplot` also likes data in long format (rather than wide format), so you'll need to `gather()` the relevant values (on y-axis) into a single column. Notice I use `gather(..., -pass_location)` to ignore the grouping column. Try the following with and without `fill=var`. Once you see that `ggplot` likes long formatted data, it becomes more intuitive to use it - at least it did for me.

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>% 
  select(-Total_Completed) %>% 
  gather(var, value, -pass_location) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=pass_location, y=value, fill=var)) + 
  geom_col()
```